# curl --data-urlencode with PAW-App

Tags: api, curl, paw-app

Trying to replicate the following curl example:

`curl -G -H "x-api-key: YOUR_API_KEY" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data-urlencode "startDate=2017-01-11T00:00:00Z" --data-urlencode "endDate=2017-01-12T00:00:00Z" https://events.jumpcloud.com/events`

within PAW App - not having any luck with data-urlencode "startDate=2017-01-11T00:00:00Z" portion.

How can I replicate that request within PAW

I already tried the curl importer and that didn't work